# Estructura LinkedList

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito un método que admita como parámetro un valor que se va a insertar en la lista. El valor se insertará en orden después de todos los que sean menores y justo antes de los que sean mayores o iguales. La lista permanecerá ordenada de menor a mayor en todo momento.

Adjunto el código

```
import random

from slt import SortedList

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_list = SortedList()

    for i in range(10):
        my_list.insert(random.randint(10, 78))

    for item in my_list:
        print(item)
```

La primera parte, la superior, no puede ser modificada porque la empleo para otra cosa

```
def add_value(self, value):
  # Este es el método que he intentado
    if value == 0:
        self.add_value(value)
    elif value == len(self):
        self.append(value)
    elif value < 0 or value > len(self):
        raise IndexError
    else:
        current = self.__first
        current_pos = 1

        while current_pos < value:
            current = current.next_node
            current_pos += 1

        current.next_node = self.Node(value, current.next_node)
        self.__len += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

cree una función que hace lo que quieres.

```
def add_value(val):
    l=[11,23,34] #lista base de ejemplo

    for i in range(len(l)): #elfor es par acomparar cada posicion de la lista

        if(val > l[i]):
            if(i == len(l)-1):#valida que el valor sea mayora todos para agregarlo al ultimo
                l.append(val)

        elif(val == l[i]):
            l.insert(i,val)#lo agrega en la misma poscion si son iguales
            break #termina el for para que no continue buscando

        elif(val < l[i]):
            l.insert(i,val)
            break#termina el for para que no continue buscando
    print(l)
    return l

#pruebas
add_value(1)
add_value(342)
add_value(24)
```

Comment: Gracias, he probado pero no consigo lo que pretendo. En la función, no es necesario crear una lista, ya que viene dada por el primer bloque de código mencionado anteriormente